# Print elements that are differents between two strings

Tags: python, list, difference

Having, for example, this two strings:

```
test1 = "line1 \n line2 \nline3"
test2 = "line1 \n line2 \nline2"
```

How could I print the entire element that is different from the first one, comparing it with the second one?

In this case I would like to print only:

```
line3
```

I am trying to do it with this code:

```
differences = [item for item in test1 if item not in test2]
print (differences)
```

But it only shows:

```
['3']
```

Comment: Are you assuming both strings are the same length? Do you have more examples?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, both strings are supposed to have the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to split two strings on spaces and newline characters, and then compare elements at each index of the lists and gather the ones that are different?

If that's the case, I'm going to assume you have data such that you get lists of the same size.

You first split(), then get elements from both the lists simultaneously using zip, and do a simple comparison.

Since you were aiming for a list comprehension, here's all of what I said in code:

```py
test1 = "line1 \n line2 \nline3"
test2 = "line1 \n line2 \nline2"

difference = [item1 for item1, item2 in zip(test1.split(), test2.split()) if item1 != item2]

print(difference)
```

Edit: Also, the problem with your code, in particular, was that you were going character by character in the string `test1`, and checking if the said character does not exist in `test2`. Well, the character `3` was the only one that didn't, so that's the reason you received that output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`set`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_difference.asp) difference.

```
test1 = "line1 \n line2 \nline3"
test2 = "line1 \n line2 \nline2"

print(set(test1.split()).difference(set(test2.split())))
```